# React Native Expo FacebookAds has extra space at the top in IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo, facebook-ads-api

When I use expo's  FacebookAds component to show BannerAd it works fine for Android, but in Ios it adds some extra space at the top and I can't solve it with styling at all.

**Component for showing banner ads**

```
import React from 'react';
import {FacebookAds} from 'expo';

const BannerAd = ({style, facebookAdsPlacementId}) => (
    <FacebookAds.BannerView 
        style={[{backgroundColor:'#888'},style]}
        placementId={facebookAdsPlacementId}
        type="standard"
        onPress= {() => console.log("Banner Ad Clicked")}
        onError= {err => console.log('Banner Ad Error', err)}
    />

);

export {BannerAd};
```

**This is how I call it**

```
<BannerAd style={{marginBottom:isIos?20:0}}
```

**and this is how it looks**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my solution to this problem

```
 <BannerAd style={{ position:isIos?"absolute":"relative", bottom:isIos?20:0 }} 
                    facebookAdsPlacementId={isIos?this.props.facebookAdsIosBanner:
                    this.props.facebookAdsAndroidBanner }/>
```

Please let me know if you have a better solution

Answer (score 0):

This can be used without extra position relative component.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bannerAd: {
    ...Platform.select<ViewStyle>({
      ios: {
        transform: [
          {
            translateY: -20,
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  },
})
```